# Script Engine - Abstract Error

Tags: delphi, pascal

Здравствуйте, недавно столкнулся с этой проблемой. При запуске выходит ошибка с данным тестом **"Abstract Error"**.
Исходный код:

```
program MFE;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses SysUtils, ScriptingEngine in 'ScriptingEngine.pas', Classes;

var
Strings: TStrings;
FileName: String;
FScriptEngine: TScriptEngine;

begin
try
FileName := ParamStr(1);
Strings := TStrings.Create();
Strings.LoadFromFile(FileName);
WriteLn(Strings.GetText);
FScriptEngine := TScriptEngine.Create;
FScriptEngine.ParseScript(nil, Strings.GetText);
FScriptEngine.Free;
except
on E: Exception do
  Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
end;
end.


unit ScriptingEngine;

interface

uses classes, sysutils;

const
ParameterDelimiter = ',';
ParameterQuoteChar = '"';

type
EIncorrentSyntax = class(Exception);
EWrongNumberOfParameters = class(Exception);
EInvalidCommand = class(Exception);

TScriptMethod = procedure(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings) of object;

TScriptCommands = class;

TScriptEngine = class
private
FScriptCommands: TScriptCommands;
procedure ParseTokens(ParamStr: string; Params: TStrings);
public
constructor Create;
destructor Destroy; override;

procedure ParseCommand(Sender: TObject; Command: string);
procedure ParseScript(Sender: TObject; Script: TStrings);
end;

TScriptCommands = class
published
procedure ShowMessage(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);
procedure Add(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);
procedure CloseApp(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);
procedure CreateFile(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);
end;

implementation

{ TScriptEngine }

constructor TScriptEngine.Create;
begin
FScriptCommands := TScriptCommands.create;
end;

destructor TScriptEngine.Destroy;
begin
FScriptCommands.Free;
inherited;
end;

procedure TScriptEngine.ParseCommand(Sender: TObject; Command: string);
var
ScriptMethodPtr: TScriptMethod;
Method: String;
Parameters: TStrings;
i, i2: integer;
begin
if command <> '' then
begin
i := pos('(', command);
i2 := pos(')', command);
if (i < 2) or (i2 < 3) then
  raise EIncorrentSyntax.Create(
    'Command parameters must start with ( and end with )');

method := trim(copy(command,1,i-1));

parameters := TStringList.Create;
try
  ParseTokens(copy(command, i+1, i2-i-1), parameters);

  TMethod(ScriptMethodPtr).Data := FScriptCommands;
  TMethod(ScriptMethodPtr).Code := FScriptCommands.MethodAddress(Method);
  if assigned(ScriptMethodPtr) then
    ScriptMethodPtr(sender, parameters)
  else
    raise EInvalidCommand.CreateFmt('Command "%s" does not exist',[method]);
finally
  parameters.Free;
end;
end;
end;

procedure TScriptEngine.ParseScript(Sender: TObject; Script: TStrings);
var
i: integer;
begin
for i := 0 to Script.Count-1 do
ParseCommand(sender, script[i]);
end;

procedure TScriptEngine.ParseTokens(ParamStr: string; Params: TStrings);
begin
params.QuoteChar := ParameterQuoteChar;
params.Delimiter := ParameterDelimiter;
params.DelimitedText := paramstr;
end;

{ TScriptCommands }

procedure TScriptCommands.Add(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);
var
i: integer;
total: integer;
begin
total := 0;
for i := 0 to params.Count-1 do
inc(total, StrToInt(params[i]));
//Dialogs.ShowMessageFmt('Total: %d', [total]);
end;

procedure TScriptCommands.CreateFile(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);
var
f: TextFile;
begin
if params.Count <> 1 then
raise EWrongNumberOfParameters.Create(
  'ShowMessage is expecting 1 parameter: Message to display');
 //f := Params[0];
AssignFile(f, Params[0]);
Rewrite(f);
WriteLn(f, '');
CloseFile(f);
end;

procedure TScriptCommands.CloseApp(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);
begin
if not (params.count in [0,1]) then
raise EWrongNumberOfParameters.Create(
  'CloseApp expects either no parameters, or 1 parameter, '+
  'being the delay to wait before closing the application.');

if params.Count = 1 then
sleep(1000 * StrToInt(Params[0]));

//if sender is TForm then
//TForm(sender).Close;
end;

procedure TScriptCommands.ShowMessage(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);
begin
if params.Count <> 1 then
raise EWrongNumberOfParameters.Create(
  'ShowMessage is expecting 1 parameter: Message to display');

WriteLn(Params[1]);
//Dialogs.ShowMessage(Params[0]);
end;

end.
```

- https://pastebin.com/ACQk6bn1

[image: Ошибка]

[image: Код]

Comment: Убери ссылки и приложи код к телу вопроса.

Comment: Владимир, добавил.

Comment: Приведите полный текст сообщения об ошибке. Укажите на какой строке дебаггер останавливается. Прочтите и выполните https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Запустите программу из под отладчика (из IDE Делфи) и увидите где конкретно вознкает исключение.

Comment: Kromster, Добавил

Comment: Kromster, Всё нормально компилируется, но ошибка никуда не уходит. Показывает, что исключение в SysUtils на 23143 строке.

Comment: Запустите программу из под отладчика (то есть, модифицируйте код, чтобы он при старте всегда читал ваш текстовый файл, и  нажмите в Делфе F9) Программа начнет выполнятся и остановится на месте с ошибкой. Откройте Call Stack и посмотрите какая из строк программы вызвалв ошибку в системной библиотеке и каким образом (что неверное было передано). Прочтите и выполните ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете `Strings: TStrings;` который является абстрактным классом. На строке `Strings.LoadFromFile(FileName);` вызывается абстрактный метод этого класса `procedure Clear; virtual; abstract;`, что и приводит к Abstract exception. Для начала замените `TStrings` на `TStringList`.

Comment: Я заменил TStrings на TStringList, и теперь у меня ошибка AccessViolation

Comment: Вот скриншот: http://prntscr.com/ipt2ov

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на метод `procedure TScriptCommands.ShowMessage(Sender: TObject; Params: TStrings);`, в нём проверяется что передан один параметр, а берется этот параметр из `TStrings` под индексом **1**, хотя индексы начинаются с нуля. Исправьте на `WriteLn(Params[0]);`.